Prove isometric embedding of $S^2$ into $\mathbf R^5$
I'm trying to solve Exercise $132$ on the last page of this pdf

Let $S^2$ denote the unit sphere. The map $f: \mathbf{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbf{R}^5$ is given by
$$
f(x, y, z)=\left(y z, z x, x y, \frac{1}{2}\left(x^2-y^2\right), \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{3}}\left(1-3 z^2\right)\right) .
$$
(i) Show that $f(\mathbf{p})=f(\mathbf{q})$ for $\mathbf{p}, \mathbf{q} \in \mathbf{R}^3$ if and only if $\mathbf{p}= \pm \mathbf{q}$.
(ii) Show that the restriction of $f$ to $S^2$ is a local isometry. So $f$ induces an isometric embedding of the elliptic plane in $\mathbf{R}^5$.

(i) By this post the map $(x,y,z) \mapsto (x^2-y^2,xy,xz,yz)$ is an embedding of $\mathbf{R}P^2$ into $\mathbf{R}^4$
(ii) If I substitute $\cases{=\sin⁡\cos⁡ϕ\\=\sin⁡\sin⁡ϕ\\=\cos⁡}$, I get
$$f(x,y,z)=(
\frac12\sin(2 θ) \sin(\phi) ,
\frac12\sin(2 θ) \cos(\phi) ,\\
\frac12\sin^2(\theta) \sin(2\phi) ,
\frac{1}{2}\sin^2(\theta) \cos(2\phi) ,
-\frac{3 \cos(2 \theta) + 1}{4 \sqrt{3}}
)$$
Then I calculate
$$f_\theta=(\cos(2 θ)\sin(ϕ),\cos(2 θ)\cos(ϕ),\\ \sin(θ)\cos(θ)\sin(2ϕ),\sin(θ)\cos(θ)\cos(2 ϕ),\sqrt3\sin(θ) \cos(θ))$$
and
$$
f_\phi=(\frac12\sin(2 θ)\cos(ϕ), -\frac12\sin(2 θ)\sin(ϕ),\\\sin^2(\theta) \cos(2\phi), -\sin^2(θ)\sin(2ϕ), 0)
$$
Then $f_\theta\cdot f_\theta=1,f_\theta\cdot f_\phi=0,f_\phi\cdot f_\phi=\sin^2(θ)$.
so $f$ is a local isometry.
This seems to involve a lot of trigonometric calculation.
Is there a better way to prove $f$ is a local isometry? Thanks

(ii) Using the approach in @Dean 's answer (without trigonometric calculation):
$$|df(x,y,z)|^2=(d(y z))^2+(d(x z))^2+(d(x y))^2+\frac{1}{4}(2 x d x-2 y d y)^2+
3 z^2(d z)^2=\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)\left((d x)^2+(d y)^2+(d z)^2\right)+ z dz d(x^2+y^2+z^2)$$
on $S^2$, $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, $d(x^2+y^2+z^2)=0$, so we get $|df(x,y,z)|^2=(d x)^2+(d y)^2+(d z)^2$.

(i): If you haven't already done so, I suggest working out the proof yourself without peeking again at the answer you linked to.
(ii) Your proof looks good to me. It is a straightforward proof without using any cleverness or tricks. That's good. The calculation is not long by differential geometry standards, especially given the lack of symmetry in the formulas.
Another possible approach that might be slightly shorter is to observe that if you denote the coordinates in the codomain by $(p,q,r,s)$, then what you want to prove is that on the sphere, $$f^*(dp^2+dq^2+dr^2+ds^2) = dx^2+dy^2+dz^2, $$ where $p,q,r,s$ are the given functions of $x,y,z$. You can confirm this (I haven't done the calculation myself) by calculating $dp, dq, dr, ds$ in terms of $x,y,z,dx,dy,dz$. This calculation might not be as straightforward as the first one, so it's not necessarily a better one.
